# Fatal Error when trying to start Box Drive

Tags: windows, cloud, box.com

When trying to start Box Drive after installation I get `Failed to execute script bfd_main` after a long wait. I've seen similar reports from users trying to run Box Sync as well.

[image: Failed to execute script bfd_main]

I'm running Windows 7 Professional.

I've tried:

- Made sure that Box Sync is uninstalled
- Reinstalled Box Drive - as administrator and/or compatibility mode for Windows 7
- Running Box Drive as Administrator
- Running Box Drive in compatibility mode for Windows 7

Non of the above steps worked.

Looking at Task Manager > Processes - I see a `Box.exe` process that hangs and no `BoxUI.exe` which usually runs in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing Box's article [Large Scale Deployments for Box Drive](https://community.box.com/t5/Deploying-Managing-Box-Drive/Large-Scale-Deployments-Box-Drive/ta-p/35830), I realized that the issue might be with the dependencies.

- I reinstalled [Update for Universal C Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)
- Repaired the installation of Microsoft .NET Framework (v4.7.2 in my case)

  And Box Drive started up with a hitch.